# Chrome debugger doesn't show Fetch requests

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, fetch-api

I don't see my [Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) AJAX data requests in the Chrome debugger? Where are they?

Answer (score 20):

To see your **Fetch** Ajax requests in the Chrome Debugger, select the `Other` option in the Network tab:

[image: Choosing the "Other" option in the Network tab]

Comment: That's weird. Why is it working this way? Isn't it supposed to be in network tab

Comment: Weird.. I swear they were in the XHR tab before. That's just silly. Fetch is supposed to be mainstream, why put it under "Other"?

Comment: I noticed that if the endpoint first redirects you, it appears under "Other".  If it does not, it appears under "XHR".

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there's an [issue created](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=806866) with chromium. You can find the requests in the all tab or Other